I got the Job Offer Contract from UAE
i got the job offer from Palmson Group LLC UAE, and the agency that handles me is Denstar Agency. Also, it is stated that i need to release money for Employment and Residency Permit and is reimbursable by employer. Is it genuine? im from the Philippines.  Thank you

Not sure this question is a good fit for this site but the first hits when googling "Palmson Group LLC" all claim that job offers are scams.

"i need to release money for [...] and is reimbursable by employer" Run away. Very fast.

Paying someone to apply for a permit is ridiculous. You most could pay the fee directly if this job was legitimate. Your being scammed.

@simonc I would encourage you to turn your comment into an answer.  I would upvote it.

Did you ever apply for that job? If not it's an obvious scam. If so it's almost certainly still a scam as if the employer reimburses the fees they can just pay them themselves, or directly pay them to you after you pay them to the UAE authorities. About the only times you'd pay a fee like that through an intermediary is if it's a non-reimbursable fee like what a travel agent charges you for a tourist visa they arrange for you (which this definitely is not).

If there were fees to pay, your employer would take them out of your first salary.

It's a scam. Stop any interactions with them. Don't send any money.
Some helpful information at : https://www.blackpearlconsult.com/post/job-seekers-beware-spotting-fake-recruitment-scams-in-the-uae
For example:

Under UAE law, it is illegal for any recruitment agency or individual to charge job seekers for securing employment. Article 18 of the UAE Labour Law clearly states that no fees should be charged to the worker for recruitment.


As the supposed fees are for government paperwork like residence permits rather than payment for arranging the job itself I'm not sure that clause would be relevant here. Doesn't mean the "offer" isn't a scam, it almost certainly is as any unsolicited job offer is almost certainly a scam, especially if payment up front for "services" is required.

Interesting argument. Since it is a pure scam and not a charge for securing employment, it doesn't violate the laws that make it illegal to charge a fee. If it was a genuine offer on the other hand it would be illegal :-)
